# DataDriven Unit Test using Excel in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, odbc, 64-bit, dsn

I am creating Datadriven Unit(MS Unit Test) Test using Excel(*.xlsx) file as data source.
it is erroring out with the following error

> Result Message:   The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data
>   source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting
>   this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests"
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
>   Error details: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The
>   specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and
>   Application

I have set the Copy to Output directory : always for the `DateRangeTest.xlsx`
I also tried `defaultdir=.\;`,  `defaultdir=.;`,  and `defaultdir=c:\projectName\bin\debug\;`

Here is the section from `app.config`

```xml
<configSections>
    <section 
      name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" 
      type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
     />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DateRangeConstr" 
      connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=DateRangeTest.xlsx;defaultdir=.\; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" 
      providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="DateRangeTestDataSource" 
        connectionString="DateRangeConstr" 
        dataTableName="Sheet1$" 
        dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

Comment: I was able to find out the problem which was related to 32 bit & 64 bit version for the driver. I changed the connection string to be DSN less and it is working now. 
  <add name="DateRangeConstr" connectionString=" Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\DateRangeTest.xls;defaultdir=.; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @NaunihalSidhu when you find the solution to your own question, you can post it as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

There are [(2) options here](http://kb.nicelabel.com/index.php?t=faq&id=255) - you can either **remove the DSN requirement** or **install the opposite Excel/Access runtime bitness** of the Office product you have installed.

#### Option 1 - remove DSN from Connection String

Change from this:

```xml
<add name="DateRangeConstr" 
    connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=DateRangeTest.xlsx;defaultdir=.\; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" 
    providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

To this:

```xml
<add name="DateRangeConstr" 
    connectionString="dbq=DateRangeTest.xlsx;defaultdir=.\; driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" 
    providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

#### Option 2 - Install ODBC Drivers for Opposite Bitness

- For Office **x64**, install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for x86 (*AccessDatabaseEngine.exe*)
- For Office **x64**, install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for x64 (*AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe*).

This fix should be the same whether you have Office 2010 or Office 2013.

To test this change - you should be able to configure the **Excel Files** DSN for both x86 and x64 once installed.

- 32-bit ODBC: `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`
- 64-bit ODBC: `%WINDIR%\System32\odbcad32.exe`

Click on "Excel Files" and then click "Configure" and you should see a dialog. If an error occurs when you click "Configure" - you don't have the proper office driver installed for that bitness.

Answer (score 0):

**We need not to install anything** to our system to run the external excel data driven unit tests.

***We need to simply run the Data Source Wizard*** present under *Visual Studio Data Source Explorer*.

Watch this video. This Tutorial tells how to run Data Driven (Parameters) unit tests using Visual Studio Testing Tools.

[image: Writing a Data Driven Unit Test using MS Excel as a Data Source Using MS Visual Studio Unit Testing Tools 2013, 2015 or 2017]